# Get total transaction count for tokens (crypto) in R?

Tags: r, api, cryptography, token, ethereum

is there a way in R or in general to get the total amount of transactions there have ever been for a token? (ERC-20)

I mean this number: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQbd3.png (Etherscan, example: uniswap)

Yeah, I could just copy the number shown there. But is there a way to do this with an API or something? Would be more "scientifically correct" for my thesis.

Thanks a lot in advance!

What I tried: explored the Etherscan API and some other APIs, didn't find a solution.

Comment: If you want to point us to a web page where the data can be scraped, we can help you, but at present your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, where questions asking for off-site resources, software, packages, books, etc is explicitly listed as a reason for question closure.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, sorry. I'm new. Yes some advice on the scraping would be nice!

Comment: but we need you to edit your question to include a URL. Web scraping is entirely dependent on the actual website being scraped, and we can't give you any general advice (other than look at the several thousand pages on this website alone about web scraping)

Comment: @AllanCameron this is the website :) https://etherscan.io/token/0x1f9840a85d5af5bf1d1762f925bdaddc4201f984